# AspNet Core Angular *NgFor does not display data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, ngfor

I have one issue related to displaying data with ngfor. It is likely that the page "displays" data before it is loaded and that is why the table is empty. I would like to delay this but I do not know how.

Empty tables:
[image]

My .ts file:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'; 

@Component({
selector: 'fetchdata',
templateUrl: './fetchdata.component.html'
})

export class FetchDataComponent {
public events: Event[];

constructor(httpClient: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {
    httpClient.get<Event[]>(baseUrl + 'api/Events').subscribe(result => {
        this.events = result;
    }, error => console.error(error));
}

}

interface Event {
  EventID: number;
  EventName: string;
  EventLocation: string;
  EventDate: Date;
  EventDesc: string;
  EventReq: number;
}
```

My .html file:

```
<h1>Events</h1>

    <p *ngIf="!events"><em>Loading...</em></p>

  <table class='table' *ngIf="events">
    <thead>
     <tr>
     <th> EventID: </th>
     <th> EventName: </th>
     <th> EventLocation: </th>
     <th> EventDate: </th>
     <th> EventDesc: </th>
     <th> EventReq: </th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let event of events">
        <td>{{ event.EventID }}</td>
        <td>{{ event.EventName }}</td>
        <td>{{ event.EventLocation }}</td>
        <td>{{ event.EventDate }}</td>
        <td>{{ event.EventDesc }}</td>
        <td>{{ event.EventReq }}</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
```

The sample data is declared. I can see them using Postman:
[image]

Would really appreciate if someone could shed some light. Thanks for your time.

Event.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ASPNETCoreAngular.Models
{
 public partial class Event
 {
    public Event()
    {
        GuestList = new HashSet<GuestList>();
    }

    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public string EventLocation { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EventDate { get; set; }
    public string EventDesc { get; set; }
    public int? EventReq { get; set; }

    public ICollection<GuestList> GuestList { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Events")]
public class EventsController : Controller
{
    private readonly TIMyContext _context;

    public EventsController(TIMyContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: api/Events
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Event> GetEvent()
    {
        return _context.Event;
    }

    // GET: api/Events/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetEvent([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var @event = await _context.Event.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.EventId == id);

        if (@event == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(@event);
    }

    // PUT: api/Events/5
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutEvent([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] Event @event)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != @event.EventId)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        _context.Entry(@event).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!EventExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return NoContent();
    }

    // POST: api/Events
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostEvent([FromBody] Event @event)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        _context.Event.Add(@event);
        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            if (EventExists(@event.EventId))
            {
                return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status409Conflict);
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return CreatedAtAction("GetEvent", new { id = @event.EventId }, @event);
    }

    // DELETE: api/Events/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteEvent([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var @event = await _context.Event.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.EventId == id);
        if (@event == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _context.Event.Remove(@event);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok(@event);
    }

    private bool EventExists(int id)
    {
        return _context.Event.Any(e => e.EventId == id);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the interface properties and response should be same. as in your case keys are different.

Comment: Is your app compiling...? the props in your constructor have no accessor specifiers... public/private ??

Comment: I have edited and added the class and controller that I use ... and yes my app is compiling

Comment: @AshishRanjan constructor arguments without a `public` or `private` declaration are local to the constructor function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response object contains `camelCased` properties. But you access them as if they are `PascalCased`. Change `event.EventID` to `event.eventId`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to change `*ngIf="events"` to `*ngIf="events!=null"`?
I think the `events` array is created when the component is loaded, therefore the for loop is working on no data.
Sorry if I'm wrong I wanted to comment only, but I don't have reputation for that.

Comment: Nothing have changed

Comment: That's exactly what I mean, I'd like the loading of the component to wait for array

Comment: so if its not null, we can try to add a flag. And instead of putting the array to the *ngIf put the flag to there.
You should be really close, because I used to do it in the same way.

Comment: The `events` array is `undefined` at the point of declaration. It will only have a value after the response has been processed.

Comment: `*ngIf="events"` ensures that `events` is not `undefined` or `null`. So that wasn't the issue :-).